# Autohotkey map Win-Z to CTRL-SHIFT-f

Tags: autohotkey

I tried to bind the key-combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> with the following command in the autohotkey configuration file:

## z::Send ^{Shift}/

But this does not work. It seems to me, the not all three keys are "presed" together. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

; Windows-z is "#z"
; Ctrl-Shift-F is "^+f"

#z::Send, ^+f

; if this fails for any reason ,try

; Send, {Ctrl Down}{Shift down}f{Shift up}{Ctrl up}

; instead